# Deleting Posts from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

I want to delete a post, if the post has equal/more then 5 dislikes. I implemented the counter part and this works already. But the post will not be deleted even if I have 6 dislikes like on this post below:

Here you can see my database.

[image]

This is the code, I want to delete the posts after 5 dislikes:

```
// Dislike Button

func addTapGestureToDislikeImageView() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDidTapDislike))
    dislikeImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    dislikeImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

}

@objc func handleDidTapDislike() {
    guard let postId = post?.id else { return }

    PostApi.shared.incrementDislikes(postId: postId, onSuccess: { (post) in
        self.updateDislike(post: post)
        self.post?.dislikes = post.dislikes
        self.post?.isDisliked = post.isDisliked
        self.post?.dislikeCount = post.dislikeCount

    }, onError: { (errorMessage) in
        ProgressHUD.showError(errorMessage)
    })
}

func updateDislike(post: PostModel) {
    if post.isDisliked == false || post.dislikes == nil {
        dislikeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-gefaellt-nicht-50")
    } else {
        dislikeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-gefaellt-nicht-filled-50")
    }

    guard let count = post.dislikeCount else { return }
    if count >= 5 {
        deletePost()
    }
}

func deletePost() {
    // Remove the post from the DB
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("posts").child((post?.id)!).removeValue { error,ref   in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Here I increment Dislikes:

```
func incrementDislikes(postId id: String, onSuccess: @escaping (PostModel) -> Void, onError: @escaping (_ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {

    let postRef = REF_POSTS.child(id)

    postRef.runTransactionBlock({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in
        if var post = currentData.value as? [String : AnyObject], let uid = UserApi.shared.CURRENT_USER_ID {

            var dislikes: Dictionary<String, Bool>
            dislikes = post["dislikes"] as? [String : Bool] ?? [:]
            var dislikeCount = post["dislikeCount"] as? Int ?? 0
            if let _ = dislikes[uid] {
                // Unstar the post and remove self from stars
                dislikeCount -= 1
                dislikes.removeValue(forKey: uid)
            } else {
                // Star the post and add self to stars
                dislikeCount += 1
                dislikes[uid] = true
            }
            post["dislikeCount"] = dislikeCount as AnyObject?
            post["dislikes"] = dislikes as AnyObject?

            // Set value and report transaction success
            currentData.value = post

            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    }) { (error, committed, snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            onError(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        guard let dic = snapshot?.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
        guard let postId = snapshot?.key else { return }
        let updatePost = PostModel(dictionary: dic, key: postId)
        onSuccess(updatePost)
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to share more information, or any error you see, or debug it and test where the action stops. But try this one maybe it will work.

```
@objc func handleDidTapDislike() {
guard let postId = post?.id else { return }

PostApi.shared.incrementDislikes(postId: postId, onSuccess: { (post) in
    self.updateDislike(post: post)
    self.post?.dislikes = post.dislikes
    self.post?.isDisliked = post.isDisliked
    self.post?.dislikeCount = post.dislikeCount
    if post.dislikeCount > 4 { 
         deletePost()
    }
}, onError: { (errorMessage) in
    ProgressHUD.showError(errorMessage)
})}
```

and then edit updateDislike() function

```
func updateDislike(post: PostModel) {
   if post.isDisliked == false || post.dislikes == nil {
       dislikeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-gefaellt-nicht-50")
   } else {
       dislikeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "icons8-gefaellt-nicht-filled-50")
   }
}
```